How can I remove a horizontal connection to a tee fitting without removing the vertical piping?
I have tried to let the threads soak in penetrating oil and then tried to use a crescent wrench, but it wont budge. Given the area its located in, I cannot use a propane torch. What are my options here?


What "horizontal connection"? Are you trying to remove the spigot?  If you're trying to remove the nipple between the tee and the elbow, that's not possible. You'd be tightening one side as you loosen the other. Revise to be more clear, please.

Assume you're talking about the pipe that goes to the elbow and the vertical pipe?

The only way to remove it without removing the vertical section is by cutting.  A hack saw will do it.
With pipes you want two wrenches always.  One to turn and one to hold.  Pipe wrenches are good for round pipes.
Removing that downspout will give you more room to work.  They are usually just attached by small screws and come apart easy.
I will assume you have a shutoff valve inside that you have turned off.

Assuming you're talking about the horizontal connection parallel to the wall: that isn't really designed to be disassembled. The threads almost certainly all go the same way so to loosen one side you would have to tighten the other, and if they're both fully tightened already...
You need to disassemble back from an end and)or find a union connection which is designed to be opened to create an end... Or cut and repair, possibly introducing a union as part of your repairs so this will be easier next time.
(A hose connection acts like a union; the threads secure a compression seal but are free to rotate Independent of the hose to release that seal.)
